# Events in Overlay Area when Modal Window is Active in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, event-handling, overlay, modal-window

I want to know how to manage or listen to events in the overlay area while the modal window is active but I am facing an issue; when my modal window is open I can still listen to events on the non-modal window behind the overlay.

Could someone please suggest how to get more information on the overlay and events on overlays?

Comment: You might want to show some code to better describe what you're trying to do. "Managing events" is rather vague. Without anything else, all I can suggest is to use the event's `target` and `currentTarget` properties to know who dispatched the event and who is handling it, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

and/or

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

if you use this when responding to the event in the overlay area, you can most likely prevent bubbling to the UI objects below it in the display list.